# Why can I not use keyof from one type on another type when both types have the same keys defined but different types for the values

Tags: typescript, types

For example. Given the following code. I get a typescript error on the last compat[k] with an error saying

> Type 'keyof T' cannot be used to index type 'Partial<CompatType>'

```
export type KeysOfType<T, U, B = false> = {
  [P in keyof T]: B extends true
    ? T[P] extends U
      ? U extends T[P]
        ? P
        : never
      : never
    : T[P] extends U
    ? P
    : never;
}[keyof T];

export type BigIntKeys<T> = KeysOfType<T, bigint, true>

export type CompatType<T> = Omit<T, BigIntKeys<T>> &
  {
    [Property in BigIntKeys<T>]: string;
  };

export function compatModel<T>(model: T): CompatType<T> {
  const compat: Partial<CompatType<T>> = {};
  for (const k of Object.keys(model) as Array<keyof T>) {
    const v = model[k];
    compat[k] = typeof v === "bigint" ? v.toString() : v;
  }
  return compat as CompatType<T>;
};
```

The types should fully overlap on their keys, but the types of the values on the objects differ. This should mean I can use the keys on one to index the other, but it's not appearing this way. Is there something I am misunderstanding or that I have wrong?

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDSxEGcDyAzAFWWAB4CAaOAVUoCE4BeOPAQwBstgA+RuAbwCwAKDhwA2gAU4ASwB2cANaYIeOAQC6ALjj1QMYLIAmWBFACuwYaNEB+NZPVw9B49SvXb1JyH1GTBB3cPTwkg4O1ZYAA3YCgw0Qjo2LDtAIlHZz83EWs7UJyEuEiYqABuYQBfMSVEFTV1cqFhUEhYBGIdaQBzAElZGAxsMh4mQdxCYjJKACNuuRhKGHNuYWbwaHgkFDgAYQgAWzAWGCIUYd4cfekYKc7e-rHhngAyd0EC8QkoCBRYRBl5LRun0BpgsMMtHAsEs5F1GqIKo01q14HgzLIAMYwaQQeQYg5HGAAWQghmAbGGAAp9qTyakAJTaPaHY6nUgEHjvUT42TQuD4lkwbQSFiwaTsEjMwlsp68PiI9x4aBwSk8vkKOB1HDTABWwCxADoalhqbS2PS4CwTABBKBQFiIEg1Ooci1c6xq+BRXg0slsaoNMICwkB3hbYB1b0MaNwABEsy681jcDsUQNMAgAGUYbIupSLdoovC4BV3FBgDAzFA8QTjpaTFLWZMOY1EUA)

Comment: It's a limitation of TypeScript as per [ms/TS#28884](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28884); the compiler cannot perform the higher order analysis to see `Exclude<keyof T, A> | Extract<keyof T, A>` as equivalent to `keyof T` when `T` is an unspecified generic type. You can rewrite `CompatType<T>` like [this](//tsplay.dev/mbGlEW) to make it clear to the compiler that `keyof CompatType<T>` is `keyof T`. You have further errors after that fix, but that's out of scope for the question as asked. If this meets your needs I can write up an answer; if not, please elaborate on unmet use cases.

Comment: Yes that helps to explain whats going on. Thanks for the answer on this. After looking at it, I've realized I've made the question way more complicated than it should be. I'll post a follow up if I can't figure out how to get the typing to work after changes.

Comment: So I can answer this question as it currently is, and you'll post a new question if you have trouble later?  Or are you planning to modify this one (and therefore I should wait to answer)?

Comment: You can answer it as is. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a design limitation of TypeScript; see [microsoft/TypeScript#28884](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28884).  According to [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28884#issuecomment-448356158), "complementary subsets of a higher order type, constructed using `Pick<T, K>` or by other means, is not assignable back to that higher order type."

So a type like `Omit<T, K> & Record<K, string>` where `K extends keyof T` is not going to be seen as having the same keys as `T`, even though it pretty much must.  The compiler compares `Exclude<keyof T, K> | Extract<keyof T, K>` and `keyof T` but does not see them as equal when `T` and/or `K` are unspecified [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) types:

```
function foo<T, K extends keyof T>(a: keyof T) {
  const b: Extract<keyof T, K> | Exclude<keyof T, K> = a; // error!
}
```

For any *specific* types `T` and `K`, the compiler can fully evaluate `Extract<keyof T, K> | Exclude<keyof T, K>` and see that it's the same as `keyof T`, but when `T` and/or `K` are not a specific type, the compiler *defers* this evaluation and thus it has no idea whether they're the same or not.

---

One thing you can do instead is to build `CompatType` as a homomorphic [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) directly from `T`, and use a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) to decide whether the particular key `K` from `keyof T` would be part of `BigIntKeys<T>` and choose the value type accordingly:

```
type CompatType<T> = { [K in keyof T]: 
  T[K] extends bigint ? bigint extends T[K] ? string : T[K] : T[K] 
}
```

This produces nicer looking types,

```
type Check = CompatType<{ a: string, b: bigint, c: number, d: boolean }>;
/* type Check = {
    a: string;
    b: string;
    c: number;
    d: boolean;
} */
```

and the compiler knows that `CompatType<T>` definitely has the same keys as `T`, even for generic `T`:

```
export function compatModel<T>(model: T): CompatType<T> {
  const compat: Partial<CompatType<T>> = {};
  for (const k of Object.keys(model) as Array<keyof T>) {
    const v = model[k];

    compat[k]; // no error here

    compat[k] = typeof v === "bigint" ? v.toString() : v; // still error here, unrelated
  }
  return compat as CompatType<T>;
};
```

Of course you still get an error when trying to assign `typeof v === "bigint" ? v.toString() : v` to `compat[k]`, but that's because the compiler doesn't really know how to verify if something is assignable to a conditional type (see [microsoft/TypeScript#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912)), nor does it understand the correlation between the type of `compat[k]` when being written to and the type of `typeof v === "bigint" ? v.toString() : v` when being read from (see [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) especially with the fact that writing to unions requires intersections as per [microsoft/TypeScript#30769](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30769)).  These problems are out of scope for the question as asked, which was just "why is `keyof` not working for me".

---

Anyway, in situations where you are sure what you are doing is correct but the compiler is not, you can use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) or [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) to loosen type checking enough to make the compiler happy.  For example:

```
export function compatModel<T>(model: T): CompatType<T> {
  const compat: Partial<Record<keyof T, any>> = {};
  for (const k of Object.keys(model) as Array<keyof T>) {
    const v = model[k];
    compat[k] = typeof v === "bigint" ? v.toString() : v;
  }
  return compat as CompatType<T>;
};
```

Here we tell the compiler not to worry about the property value types of `compat`, and we just return it `as CompatType<T>`.  As long as you are definitely 100% sure that the typings are correct, this is fine to do.  Although, you probably shouldn't be so sure:

```
const hmm = compatModel({ a: Math.random() < 10 ? 3n : 3 });
hmm.a // number | bigint
if (typeof hmm.a !== "number") {
  3n * hmm.a; // no error at compile time, but runtime  "can't convert BigInt to number" 
}
```

The type of the `a` property is `number | bigint`, which according to either definition of `CompatType<{a: number | bigint}>` will turn into `{a: number | bigint}` instead of the correct `{a: number | string}`.  And so the compiler thinks `hmm.a` might be a `bigint` even though that is impossible.  There are fixes here too, but these are also out of scope and the answer is already longer than I'd like.

This is just a warning that you should take great care when using type assertions or `any` to overcome compiler errors, since you are making it more likely that errors like this could leak through.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=18&ssc=3&pln=17&pc=34#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcA8AVANIg0ogUwA8oCwATAZ0QGsCBPOYRDAPgAoBDALloaZYBKRAG8AsAChEiCAkpREAI14BREgCdO0NHUbNseVogA+iNRAA2IcgR399OXEYC8iTgG5EAei+F16uHUAQkkAX0kIiWIAB0CFKHpogkQAYTgAW2jOKAxE2zZEVxFEAG18GCRdAQwAXV4MMprCEjIqJRgAcwqFAH52rrAFYlIKagbcJr75dQqOxHrG+ZZF8IlJGLjkcGh4JFlM7IBZOBsLTA50k4ILesFeNIOcvPPRSWlZMHkZDKyoXgAFTjqWCcM4PX65JLnFyiULuN7IQKIdgfL40RACADyigAVgRoAA6XSUdiXU7CTjUACC-k49DsehYrGE4ik0m+nwUADdCogydcSjQavC1mz3j9soLhd5fGA4H4AupEAALAjqAiRdnfR5S3kJJICHnOY2IABEik63VNiD6XIJUDgAGUoDMwB12MJeFzPD5EPIYBYLAqkar1ThwOqLNkCOQEatpOqoCB1HsJQpKak05D8qwRXDIvrkilVRB0a5wdls2hijw-S7ZjhlP1ujgILwwCB0oo1ThyLxFKgLAROEhQrnJF4AFSIQupEtl15ity8aazEVapurt3r9ltxAdrtqnfSPtKQfDsB5xCTrxAA)